# Dropdown list and web service with persistence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml, persistence

I have a web service that I want to use as the source of my dropdown. This web service updates it's data once a week.

Now I don't think that calling the web service every time I show the dropdown is a good idea in this case, since the data only gets updated weekly.

The web service output is XML, so I thought about putting it in a file and use linq to xml to read the file and populate the drop down. But I fear threading issues if multiple users are the same page and need to populate the same dropdown.

My next thought is to store the xml in a local database contained in the app_data directory, multiple reads to the db file should be thread safe.

So I guess my question is how can I read the xml data to populate the dropdown when it is stored in a database is it linq to xml, linq to sql?

Also how do I get my app to call the service one a week to refresh the local database?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing it in a database by using LINQ to XML then obvious option to read it back is LINQ TO SQL. But you can store the XML file itself and use it as datasource for your drop down list. You just have to write utility which will update your XML file with new output from webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have the following methods:

```
DateTime ComputeLastPublicationDate();

List<Item> GetListFromWebService();

void StoreListToLocalStorage(List<Item> list, DateTime queryDateTime);

List<Item> GetListFromLocalStorage(out DateTime queryDateTime)
```

The last one returns null if the list was never stored localy.

```
private object itemsLock = new object();
private DateTime? lastQuery = new DateTime();
private List<Item> items;

public List<Item> Items
{
    get
    {
        DateTime lastPublication = ComputeLastPublicationDate();

        if (items != null && lastQuery >= lastPublication)
            return items;

        lock (itemsLock)
        {
            // lock double check
            if (items != null && lastQuery >= lastPublication)
                return items;

            // not yet retrieved locally 
            if (items == null)  
            {
                items = GetListFromLocalStorage(out lastQuery);
            }
            if (item == null || lastQuery < lastPublication)
            {
                items = GetListFromWebService();
                lastQuery = DateTime.Now;
                StoreListToLocalStorage(items, lastQuery);
            }
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect this will help.